# c# wpf - ListView.ScrollIntoView(LastItem) does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, event-handling, scrollbar

like some other people here i have a ListView (updated via binding in a GridView).
I want to keep the last inserted Item in the View. So i tried

```
LView.ScrollIntoView(LView.Items[LView.Items.Count - 1]);
```

This is working almost fine. Altough the first item which would have to be scrolled into view is only shown like 80% of its whole row (depending on how high i define the whole ListView, i almost got 100%).

The real problem is that the following items which should get scrolled into view are not shown. It is also noticable at the Scrollbar itself which is not at the bottom.

[Last Item is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xpSE.jpg)

Here is the code of my MainWindow.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private InterfaceCtrl ICtrl;
    private ListView LView;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ICtrl = new InterfaceCtrl();
        this.ICtrl.ProgressCollection.CollectionChanged += this.CollectionChanged;

        Grid MainGrid = new Grid();
        this.Content = MainGrid;

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        Binding StartTimeStampBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("StartTS"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, StringFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss.fff" };
        GridViewColumn gvTCStartTS = new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Time", Width = 150.00, DisplayMemberBinding = StartTimeStampBinding };
        gv.Columns.Add(gvTCStartTS);

        LView = new ListView() { Height = 192, Width = 250, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, View = gv, ItemsSource = this.ICtrl.ProgressCollection };

        MainGrid.Children.Add(LView);

        ICtrl.StartMyThread();
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Action(delegate ()
        {
            if (LView != null && LView.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                LView.UpdateLayout();
                //LView.ScrollIntoView(LView.Items[LView.Items.Count - 1]);

                LView.SelectedIndex = LView.Items.Count;
                LView.ScrollIntoView(LView.SelectedItem);                    
            }

        }));
    }

}
```

Thank you.

---

EDIT:
It seemed to be a timing problem, although all the wanted data was in the LView at the right time i tried a workaround with a Textbox bound to the Timestamp.

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox(); // { Width = 250, Height = 28, Margin= new Thickness(10,100,1,0)};
        tb.SetBinding( TextBox.TextProperty , new Binding("LastMsgTimestamp") { Source = this.ICtrl, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, StringFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss.fff" });

        tb.TextChanged += this.UpdateScrollbar;
        tb.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

It seems to me like there is a timing issue within the binding to the LView and the fired Event of the ObservableCollection. This also includes the PropertyChanged of the ObservableCollection.

I tried the events TargetUpdated and SoruceUpdated directly within LView but those didn't came up at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to call any of the `ScrollToBottom()` or `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` methods of the `ListView`'s internal `ScrollViewer` element:

```
private void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Action(delegate ()
    {
        if (LView != null && LView.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            LView.UpdateLayout();
            ScrollViewer sv = GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(LView);
            if (sv != null)
                sv.ScrollToBottom();

            LView.SelectedIndex = LView.Items.Count;
            LView.ScrollIntoView(LView.SelectedItem);
        }

    }));
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I still have the same problem. But i have a workaround (ugly but working).
The Listview has all the wanted data, altough it seems the CollectionChanged event which triggers the scrollintoview is fired to early.
The Workaround contains a Textbox which is bound to the Timestamp of the ictrl class.
The TextChanged event now triggers the scrollintoview at the correct Time. Yes it's ugly programming but i can hide the Textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I have made the following sample. You could try to call ScrollToBottom in inner ScrollViewer as @mm8 points out. Nevertheless when saw the answer I was already making my sample, so here it is:

Codebehind

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace ListViewScroll
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ListView.ItemsSource = Names;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Names.Add("Some Name" + ++someInt);
            // Get the border of the listview (first child of a listview)
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ListView, 0) as Decorator;

            // Get scrollviewer
            var scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
            scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
        }

        private static int someInt;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewScroll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Name="ListView"/>

        <Button Content="Add" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1"
                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case I am handling the scrolling in the button click event but you may change this to fit your requirements

[image]

It works, I have tested.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I still have the same problem. But i have a workaround (ugly but working).
The Listview has all the wanted data, altough it seems the CollectionChanged event which triggers the scrollintoview is fired to early.
The Workaround contains a Textbox which is bound to the Timestamp of the ictrl class.
The TextChanged event now triggers the scrollintoview at the correct Time. Yes it's ugly programming but i can hide the Textbox.